# numpy loadtxt skip rows with incorrect number of columns

Tags: python, numpy, data-import

My data can have some erroneous rows which contain less columns. How can I skip these rows when I load the data using `loadtxt` such that it continues instead of throwing an error?

Example:

Data in file=

```
0    4.5    523.1    2.2   432123.5
1    4.21   529.5    3.4   432122.3
2    4.15   526.2    4.6   432122.6
3    4.54   523.7    
4    4.65   527.5    5.0   432121.8
5    4.75   521.4    5.0   432121.1
```

Resulting imported data should be the data from the file without the erroneous row:

```
0    4.5    523.1    2.2   432123.5
1    4.21   529.5    3.4   432122.3
2    4.15   526.2    4.6   432122.6
4    4.65   527.5    5.0   432121.8
5    4.75   521.4    5.0   432121.1
```

Comment: Could `numpy.genfromtxt` be helpful?

Comment: I was not yet aware of `numpy.genfromtxt` but that solves my issue. Thanks